# Creating multiple has_many :through records with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, form-for

I have a subscription model, a subscription can many eliquids through a subscription choices. My three models:

subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscription_choices
    has_many :eliquids, through: :subscription_choices
    has_one :address
    belongs_to :subscription_plan

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription_choices, allow_destroy: true
end
```

subscription_choice.rb

```
class SubscriptionChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscription
    belongs_to :eliquid
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :eliquid
end
```

eliquid.rb

```
class Eliquid < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscription_choices
end
```

I want to be able to build multiple subscription_choices from one form submission. I'm struggling to get multiple subscription_choices into params from my form_for. The form looks like this:

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @subscription, html: {role: "form", id: "signUp"} do |subscription_form| %>
     <% for i in 1..3 %>
         <%= subscription_form.select(:subscription_choices, options_from_collection_for_select(@eliquids, 'id', 'name')) %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to create 3 choices of eliquid. When the form gets submitted each subscription choice gets overrriden so I only end up with the final choice, params looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"subscription" => { "subscriptions_choices" => "3" }}
```

What I want to achieve is this (or something like this):

```
Parameters: {"subscription" => { "subscription_choices" => [1, 2, 5] }}
```

I could do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @subscription, html: {role: "form", id: "signUp"} do |subscription_form| %>
     <% for i in 1..3 %>
         <%= select_tag("subscription_choice_#{i}", options_from_collection_for_select(@eliquids, 'id', 'name')) %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which will give me some params like this:

```
Parameters: { "subscription_choice_1" => "1", "subscription_choice_2" => "3", "subscription_choice_3" => "5" }
```

And I could iterate over these params in my controller and save the choices, but my gut is telling me that there must be a better rails way. This doesn't seem like a really niche use case, I think I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For managing associations via a form, I would recommend using [simple form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). With simple form, this becomes:

```
<%= f.input :eliquid_ids, collection: @eliquids %>
```

If you don't like simple form, you can create your select tag for the `eliquid_ids` attribute.

```
<%= select_tag("subscription[eliquid_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@eliquids, 'id', 'name')) %>
```

Assigning `eliquid_ids` will automatically create the `SubscriptionChoice` join model records.

Answer (score 0):

Add the option:

```
multiple: true
```

to the `select_tag` helper. The tag should end up with brackets after the name, so that they are submitted as an array value. E.g.

```
<select name="subscription[subscription_choices][]">
```

The [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) explain the various options for the tag helpers. You might also look at [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).